Transaction Priority in Producing Block
I've got one question about priority in ethers mempool tx.
I've checked all transactions in some blocks, discovered that they are not confirmed in order of gas fee,
even the tx with lower fee confirmed before the one with high fees.
What's going on?

tl;dr validators can include transactions in whatever order they want.
Many times validators order transactions based on their priority fees. However, transactions are often placed in different orders to maximize the extractable value (MEV). See Flashbots
